# why is on progress update not showing the right progress

Tags: android, asynchronous, task, progress

I am using a AsyncTask to get data from a Database.
To notify the User how much data is downloaded I'm using a ProgressDialog and onProgressUpdated - but it won't show the "right" progress. In my case it only displays "Loading... 0%"

```
AsyncTask<>
{    
...
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
          ...
          this.publishProgress(i, size);            
          Thread.sleep(500); // Just to make the Progress visible
        }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading... " + values[0] / values[1]*100 + "%");
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: because you are performing a division between integer values.

Comment: no of course it won't, but (int)((values[0]/(float)values[1]) * 100), probably will

Answer (score 0):

Try this
this.publishProgress(100 / (size - I));

In on your onProgressUpdate do this
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading... " + values [0]);

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - but Blackbelt already had the solution - i had a integerdivison. protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) and  this.publishProgress((float)i, (float)size); fixed the problem